# Spacing dynamic nav items purely with CSS

Tags: html, css

I know I can achieve this using javascript, however I was wondering if anyone had any bright ideas how this could be done with pure CSS so I can avoid the "jumpy" effect that would be caused by performing various calculations after the DOM loads and the styles are applied or having to use a loading gif on every page change to hide this.

Basically, a nav has a fixed width, say 960. The site is CMS driven so the client could have 2 menu items or 10 menu items. The menu items should be sized according to the length of the text contained within them and each menu item should had uniform padding like so:

[image]

[image]

Ideally, I'd like to avoid the use of tables. I'm pretty sure what I'm trying to achieve is not possible though

Comment: remove fixed width and add padding:5px 10px; 5px for top+bottom and 10px for left and right spacing..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is called as Flex-Box (flexible box) model. It is not implemented in all the browsers. For testing purposes, yeah, you can go ahead with the following CSS.

**CSS**

```
ul li {
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    display: -moz-box;
    -moz-box-orient: horizontal;
    display: box;
    box-orient: horizontal;
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -moz-box-flex: 1;
    box-flex: 1;
}
```

You can see basic and advanced examples at [Quick hits with the Flexible Box Model](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/flexbox/quick/).

---

**Flexbox Model Layouts**

Normal Box
http://1-ps.googleusercontent.com/x/s.html5rocks-hrd.appspot.com/www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/flexbox/quick/475x297xflex01.gif.pagespeed.ic.I78_V3_QCI.webp
Flexbox for the last one
http://1-ps.googleusercontent.com/x/s.html5rocks-hrd.appspot.com/www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/flexbox/quick/475x297xflex02.gif.pagespeed.ic.sSh_w3N6ER.webp
Flexbox for last two
http://1-ps.googleusercontent.com/x/s.html5rocks-hrd.appspot.com/www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/flexbox/quick/475x297xflex03.gif.pagespeed.ic.QuC9JhvmNd.webp

Comment: I've never even heard of this before. I will look into it. Thanks!

Comment: Sure. But it is coming up now only. :)

Comment: @Fraser Added screenshots too. Check it out. :)

Comment: Thanks. I got it to work like so: http://goo.gl/dE9hr going to take a lot of tinkering for various browsers though.